# PlantUML, one generic class - with many different occurences - on 1 diagram

Tags: plantuml

In PlantUML, is it possible to show - on one diagram - many differently parametrized, one generic class?
Like here:

```
@startuml
class List<String>
class List<Long>
class List<Integer>
@enduml
```

In my case it shows only `class List<Integer>`
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `as` fixes this:

```
@startuml
class "List<String>" as ListString
class "List<Long>" as ListLong
class "List<Integer>" as ListInteger
@enduml
```

[image]